# How to disable rangeslider in jQuery Mobile via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, disabled-input, rangeslider

I'm trying to properly disable a jQuery Mobile rangeslider via Javascript. But it doesn't work. If I add the `disabled` attribute to the `<input>` Elements in the Html file it works. But then if I try to disable it via

```
$('#range-monday-a').attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('#range-monday-b').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

it adds `disabled="disabled"` attribute to the input elements in the DOM, but the display doesn't change and I can still use the slider. ("#range-monday-a" and "#range-monday-b" are the ids of both input elements of the rangeslider)

I assume that's because jQuery Mobile renders additional divs and stuff for the rangeslider. But I can't find the answer on jquerymobile.com, nor here or via google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$('#range-monday-a').slider('disable');
$('#range-monday-b').slider('disable');
```

From docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/forms/slider/methods.html

Comment: Thanks so much, indeed this works! It was right in front of my eyes, but for some reason I thought this version only works for sliders that are initialized via javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with a single selector:

```
$("#range-monday-a, #range-monday-b").slider("disable");
```

Or even better:

```
$("#ancestor input[data-type='range']").slider("disable");
```

However, note that the numeric fields at both sides will remain at full opacity in any case - [I filed the bug](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6532).